# Incompatible pointer type in C. C arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, incomplete-type

I have been getting a compiler error incompatable pointer type. Here is the code.

```
#define MAX_WORDS 10000
#define MAX_CHAR_PER_WORD 100

char textn[MAX_WORDS][MAX_CHAR_PER_WORD];


void foo(char *text[], int nlines){
// Code
}

int main(){

    foo(*textn,number_of_words);

}
```

Here char *textn[] is an array of pointer and *textn would also point to an array of pointers.

Comment: A pointer array is *not* a 2D array. And `foo` expects an array of pointer-to-char, you're feeding it an array of char.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `foo` expects a pointer-to-pointer-to-char (`char**`).

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Here pointer to char is textn, but even if I pass foo(textn,number_of_words), it still has the same error.

Comment: @Pavan I'd say read my original comment, but apparently the gross inaccuracy of said same, whether I'm fully aware of what it means vs the context of how you were *trying* to use it, makes it utterly meaningless, so I'll just be moving on.

Comment: Can you tell us what your question is?

Answer (score 2):

textn is any array of array of char.  But array decays to pointer when you write (*textn), so textn becomes a pointer to an array of char. Then *textn is an array of char